# How to cascade a user defined operation on an entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to figure out a way to cascade an operation on all entities associated with an entity. For example, if I have a User, and a user has entities, and those entities have entities, I want to perform an operation on every entity. Specifically I want to perform validation on every entity in that tree.

How would I implement something like 'getAssociatedEntities()':

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Comment")
     */
    private $comment;
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Something")
     */
    private $something;
}

$user->setComment($comment);
$user->setSomething($something);
$associated_entities = $user->getAssociatedEntities(); // NOT A REAL METHOD

foreach ($associated_entities AS $entity) {
    validate($entity);
}
```

I realize I could use lifecycle callbacks to perform validation. However, setting validation annotations makes things sooooo much easier. I can validate every entity I persist, BUT I can't validate its associated entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can validate every entity I persist, but I can't validate its
>   associated entities.

Of course you can perform any action to entitied associated with main entity if:

1. You add `cascade={"all"}` to `@ManyToOne` definition (**required !**).
2. `@HasLifecycleCallbacks` for each sub-entity you want action performed and mark methods `@PrePersist` or `@PostPersist` [or more in documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#implementing-event-listeners).

For example I use this method to cascade deletion of image file in the `Image` entity, while the any entity that contains `Image` entity is beeing deleted:

Here **I have an livecycle callback**:

```
/**
 * An image.
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="images")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class ImageEntity extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove
     */
    public function preRemoveDeleteFile()
    {
        // remoce file
    }
}
```

Here I have an entity that contains Image (**where there is a cascade operation** defined):

```
/**
 * A competency group name.
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_meta_image_cover")
 */
class ProductMetaImageCoverEntity extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var \ModuleModel\Entity\ImageEntity
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ModuleModel\Entity\ImageEntity", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $image;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, you didn't answer the question. I have come to the conclusion that there isn't a way to cascade an operation on an entity. The best that can been done is use lifecycle callbacks, which I already addressed in the question. The problem with callbacks is they only occur during actions like persist, load, and remove. You're out of luck if you want to do an action any other time. However, I now think this is good. If you can't do it with lifecycle callbacks, you probably shouldn't be doing it :)